# How to get repository statistics with JGit

Tags: java, github, jgit

The statistics I want to pull about a repository include those offered by the Github statistics API
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/

My question is, is this possible using the library JGit?

From my research using stack over flow and Google, there is little, if any information that is clear about this. At this point I am doing research prior to starting a project, so example lines of code or even a guaranteed yes\no answer from experienced users is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the repository holds the information you are looking for, it can be retrieved by using the JGit API.

A `RevWalk` can be used to traverse the commits of a repository and a `TreeWalk` in can be used to iterate the tree of a commit, i.e. the list of files the commit consists of. With a `DiffFormatter`, two commits can be compared and a list of `DiffEntry`s can be obtained that describe the added, removed and modified files.

Some time ago I wrote an [article that might also be of interest](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/). It touches the JGit APIs to read and write Git objects (commits, trees and blobs).

You may also want to look into [*gitective*](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective): a library that provides an API on top of JGit to make investigating Git repositories simpler and easier. 
While the project is unmaintained in the meanwhile it may either still work or can at least be used to learn how to use certain JGit APIs.

Comment: Okay thanks! On another note, is it possible to read statistics from a repository (via URL) without cloning?

Comment: To do anything meaningful with a Git repository, you have to clone it first. This is not a limitation of JGit but inherent to the design of Git. Any operation other than synchronizing a repository with its remote requires a local copy.

Comment: Thanks, ive been looking into extracting repository issues. is this possible using jgit? i cant find any examples of this

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. What are 'repository issues' and what does 'extracting' them mean?

Comment: I mean things like known bugs associated with projects on github, can jgit get that information.

Comment: No, JGit is a Java implementation of the Git version control system. See this page: https://developer.github.com/libraries/ for an overview of language bindings for the GitHub REST API.

Comment: Ah understand now, your help is appreciated

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I have a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795781/how-to-write-git-log-stat-command-in-jgit would you mind to give it a shot. thx