# How to write git log --stat command in JGit

Tags: java, jgit

I have following git command:

```sh
git log --stat=1000 --all > gitstat.log
```

Is it possible to achieve this in JGit?

If yes, what is the equivalent way to write this in JGit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the history of a repository, JGit provides the `RevWalk`. Its `markStart()` method is used to specify at which commits the history should start.
All refs in a repository can be obtained with `Repository::getAllRefs()`.

Once a `RevWalk` instance is set up, use its iterator or its `next()` method to traverse the history.

Putting that together would look like this:

```java
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
  for (Ref ref : repository.getAllRefs().values()) {
    revWalk.markStart(revWalk.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId()));
  }
  for (RevCommit commit : revWalk) {
    // print commit metadata and diff
  }
}
```

Note that the `RevWalk` instance that calls `parseCommit()` must be the same as the one that calls `markStart()`. Otherwise, the `RevWalk` will yield funny results.

Once you have a commit (and through this, access to its parent) you can use the `DiffFormatter` to obtain a list of `Diff`s and `Edit`s that tell how many files and lines per file were changed.

You may want to look at this post to get started: [How to show changes between commits with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361538/how-to-show-changes-between-commits-with-jgit)

And here for an article that covers JGit's diff APIs in depth: http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/06/16/jgit-diff/

Comment: Not sure what 'total lines added, deleted in repo' means. You can, of course, calculate the number of lines added/removed between two commits. The link to the article in the answer, in particular the list of `Edit`s  should get you there.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you follow the links in the answer? They should contain everything you need.

Comment: `getAllRefs().values()` is deprecated now. use `getRefDatabase().getRefs()` instead.